# Wien Bridge Frequency Selective Network Frequency Response Proof Exam Question

Tags: oscillator, impedance, bridge

[image: Wien Bridge Exam Question]

So this is part of the solution to the proof of what the frequency response on the frequency select section of the Wien Bridge oscillator.

What I don't understand is how the answer are equal to the simplified form. Something I'm missing about impedances?

Comment: You're asking about the equation in the dotted box? Take the first version and multiply both the numerator and denominator by sC and you get the final version.

Comment: Yeah I don't really get your question. Of course \$Z_{||}\$ and \$Z_S\$ are two different things, while all the other equalities are just some basic algebra, nothing fancy about impedances is involved.

Comment: I suppose, you are asking for the transfer function of the combined circuit, correct? The answer is simple: Use the voltage divider rule for both impedances because the common node between the series and the parallel combination of this Wien circuit (it is NOT a "bridge") is used to form the bridge using two additional resistors.

Answer (score 1):

To combine impedances in parallel: consider two parallel impedances Z1, Z2 then

Zparallel = (Z1)(Z2)/(Z1+Z2)

Considering series impedances then clearly they sum:

Zseries = Z1 + Z2

That's all that's going on in the equations above.